# default user mongodb with django_restframework_mongoengine?

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine, django-rest-framework

I am using `django_restframework_mongoengine` in a project and I need to know if it exists, and how to use the default user of mongodb. As well as the user of django with its ORM, I have some possibility with an ODM?

Comment: Just found the answer !!! :) "MongoEngine includes a Django authentication backend, which uses MongoDB. The User model is a MongoEngine Document, but implements most of the methods and attributes that the standard Django User model does - so the two are moderately compatible."